# Can a Chrome extension get information about a connection?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, https, connection

I want my Chrome extension to collect information about how the current browser [tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) negotiated its secure connection.

In particular, I want to know the protocol and the cypher/auth & key exchange mechanisms used in the HTTPS connection: `SSL3`? `TLS 1.2`? And those ugly strings like `AES_128_GCM` or `CHACHA20_POLY1305`, `ECDHE_RSA` or `ECDHE_ECDSA`.

Is this even possibile?

Within the [API index](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index), the best fitting module seems to be [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). But I can't see any means to gather connection data. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get any information about the TLS connection via the Chrome extension APIs. A few days ago, a popular feature request on Chromium's issue tracker was marked as WontFix because of the complexity of implementing such a feature in Chrome ([Issue 107793: Provide information about the TLS connections to extensions via the webRequest API](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107793)).

The only way to get the certificate information in Chrome is by clicking on the lock icon, then the Connection tab.